# How Resolve Permission denied problem while launching react app using npm start in Mac Os?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following error, tried several ways but nothing is working..please help me out with this.. I am doing this on Mac os

Failed to compile.

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/akashjana/.config/svgrrc'
ERROR in ./src/logo.svg
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js):
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/akashjana/.config/svgrrc'

webpack compiled with 1 error

I was expecting to launch the starting page of react app just after creating the react file using
"npx create-react-app myapp but after entering that directory and entering the command npm start
it was showing the previously mentioned error.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to: Computers > MacintoshHD > Users > `{username of PC}`
2. Press `command + shift + .` to show hidden files on your PC
3. Click on `.config`
4. Get info > sharing and permission
5. Click on the lock bar and provide your system password
6. Click on `+` sign
7. Add user or guest
8. Select your `{user name}` and set privileges to read and write.

Answer (score 2):

this error is because some of packages are not installed,

like for me `@svgr/webpack` is not installed. so steps are like

1. Clear npm cache `npm cache clean --force` this will clean cache.
2. Delete Node module `sudo rm -R node_modules`.
3. Install the modules `npm i`.
4. Install package which is **not installing**. Like for me `npm i @svgr/webpack.
5. **Give permission of config file** `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.config`.

Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: For me just giving access to the `.config` file with `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.config` worked.